# Struts tag lib errors while deploying on JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, struts-1

All,

I have an application using struts 1.1 which I am trying to migrate to JBOSS from Weblogic.

I  see the below errors in log which I am unable to resolve.

```
17:39:37,317 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.ForwardTag due to an except
ion (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)**
17:39:37,320 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.HiddenTag due to an excepti
on (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
17:39:37,321 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.MultiboxTag due to an excep
tion (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
17:39:37,322 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.CheckboxTag due to an excep
tion (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
17:39:37,378 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.IfParameterEqualsTag due to
 an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
**17:39:37,379 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.IfParameterNotEqualsTag due
 to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)**
17:39:37,380 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.SubmitTag due to an excepti
on (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
17:39:37,381 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.CancelTag due to an excepti
on (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
17:39:37,383 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011006: Not in
stalling optional component org.apache.struts.taglib.PropertyTag due to an excep
tion (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
```

Can someone help?

I am using JBOSS EAP  & JAVA 8. struts-1.1.jar is in lib directory along with other jar files . I have set debug to 6 in the init-parameter of struts but I don't see any errors in application logs.

Comment: Have you tried adding debug for the class. It is most likely an Issue related to a missing dependency in the module.xml (Assuming EAP 6 / 7 ) and you have set up struts as a module.

Comment: Hi @KennethClark , Are you asking about setting DEBUG log level? I tried setting it up in log4j but I didn't see any error.  Also I have not added any struts lib in module.xml, Module.xml contents:   ` <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.app.configuration"> 
    <resources> 
        <resource-root path="."/> 
    </resources> 
</module>`